# Passing SQL Statement In Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with SAP Crystal Reports 13.0.5. I have a class that connects to my SQL database and passes the update or select statement. I have one report that I am passing the update statement just fine, however when I pass my select statement the report doesn't select the value that I have passed. I didn't create the report either, but no matter what value I pass the report it always loads the same thing.

```
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = null;
            crystalReportViewer1.Visible = false;
            var cr_singlepo = new singlepo();

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr_singlepo;
            //Database connection and info method
            meth_database_connection_info();
            //SQL view statements for lowlumber report
            var new_DB_Statements = new DB_Statements();

            var string_sql = ("SELECT PO.PO_Num, PO.Supplier, PO.DateOrdered, PO.DateRequired, PO.Terms, PO.Freight, PO.FOB, POItems.PO_Num, POItems.Quantity, POItems.Description, POItems.Item, POItems.Price, POItems.KeyNum FROM PO, POItems WHERE PO.PO_Num = POItems.PO_Num and PO.PO_Num =" + cmb_existing_po.SelectedItem);
            new_DB_Statements.SelectFromDB(string_sql);

            crystalReportViewer1.Visible = true;

            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

Is there a way to use a "SQLQuery" in VS 2010, like you could in crystal reports 8? If there is anything else that I can post to help, please let me know. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is changing the visibility of the viewer and is refreshing it, but it is not clear where the data is passed to the report.

Comment: That is the problem that I am having. I am not sure how to pass the data to the report.